# How to make a relation between two table using has_one but none of them stores id of its adjacent table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a table name Strategy which looks like this:

```
+---+  +----+  +---+  
|id |  | a  |  | b    
+---+  +----+  +---+  
|1  |  |  1 |  | 2 |  
|2  |  |  2 |  | 3 |  
|3  |  |  2 |  | 4 |  
|4  |  |  4 |  | 1 |  
|5  |  |  4 |  | 4 |  
+---+  +----+  +---+
```

and I have a class name Plan which looks like:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :a, :b
  has_one :strategy  ...................
end
```

Now I want to fill this empty `has-one` relation. Strategy table has column `a` and `b` and two column will always have different combination as shown in table. Now  I dont know how to build a relation ship on between two table because Strategy table doesn't belong to Plan nor Plan table store strategy table id. Strategy table only contains some static values. But Plan has some a and b value and I want the id of Strategy Table on the basis of plan's `a` and `b` value using `has_one` relation. Is it possible in rails to do that or I need to follow some old logic.

Comment: You say that the Strategy table has columns `a` and `b` before the first ASCII-art but in your description you also say that "Plan has some a and b value". Which one is it?

Comment: In Plan table I have columns a and b and I want the Strategy table ID on the basis of a and b eg in my case lets suppose a = 2 and b = 3 so I want some thing like plan.strategy = strategy_obj and strategy_obj.id = 2. Hopefully it clear my question

Comment: The answer from Steve is the way to go. Just remove the has_one declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an association manually.

in your Plan model

```
def strategy
  @strategy ||= Strategy.where("a = ? AND b = ?", a, b).first
end
```

this will let you reference my_plan.strategy in your code

EDIT answer updated to include Chandranshu's excellent suggestions... memoization and handling the case of more than one strategy with duplicate a, b values

Comment: Could you please update your answer to cache the strategy like this: `@strategy ||= Strategy.where().first`? (Notice the first too.)